# express req.session is empty in another route

Tags: node.js, express

Any suggestions? Express req.session is empty in another route.

It can print at the following route:

`Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  user: 
   { _id: 586fa96dc53c951778993d3d,
     username: '123',
     password: '$2a$10$LvasklkF5TeAaAeCrzNoiulPwTcj4jC3Iz3zGaOBWo9N4syXFjJDe',
     userid: 20130610040208,
     class: '13计算机二班',
     __v: 0,
     meta: 
      { updateAt: 2017-01-06T14:27:57.740Z,
        createAt: 2017-01-06T14:27:57.740Z } },
  userid: 20130610040208,
  username: '123' }`

```
console.log(user)
req.session.userid = user.userid
req.session.username = user.username
c onsole.log('sesesese')
console.log(req.session)
console.log(req.session.userid)
console.log('Is matched!')
res.send({status: 1,userid: req.session.userid})
console.log(req.session)
console.log(req.session.userid)
```

But when I use another route, req.session is empty:

`Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }`

```
router.get('/logStatus',function(req, res) {
console.log(req.session.cookie)
console.log(req.session.username)
if (req.session) {
    res.send( {userid: req.session.userid,username: req.session.username} )
} else {
    res.send({status: 0})
}})
```

Here is my app.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(session({
  secret: 'sessionsecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie:{ path: '/', httpOnly: true, secure: false, maxAge: null }
}))
app.use('/',index)
app.use('/admin',admin)
app.use('/test',test)
```

I have stored it in mongoDB,I use react and fetch,when I fetch,the mongo session store will add sessions, are they buried the original session?

Comment: I use mongo to store the session, and I find that every fetch create a new session in mongo.How could it been that, I am so confused and completely don't know what's the issue .Could sb help me ? I have tried a long time and there is no progress.

Comment: It isn't undefined now ,but an empty session.`Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: false,
     secure: false } }`